# C# ASP.NET Wrap dynamically added CheckBox Control with a dynamically added Label Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, label

I want the checkbox wrapped in a label so that if they click the `Label` it will check the `CheckBox`.  I also need the descArea to diplay once the hover over the `Label`.  These must also be dynamic and created in the code behind.  I have 2 ways so far, both with their own issue...

This option doesn't allow the JS functions to be called for the descArea to slide down

```
caPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
                "<div class='col-md-6'>"+
                    "<div id='AButton" + t.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "' class='caLabel' onmouseenter='slideDescriptionDown(this.id);' onmouseleave='slideDescriptionDown(this.id);' >" +
                        "<label>"));

                            CheckBox aCheckBox = new CheckBox();
                            aCheckBox.ID = "checkbox" + t.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
                            caPanel.Controls.Add(aCheckBox);

                ca.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;" + t.Rows[i]["NAME"].ToString() + 
                        "</label>"+
                    "</div>"+
                    "<div class='alert alert-info aDescription' id='descArea" + t.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "'>" +
                        "<span id='desc" + t.Rows[i]["CA_ID"].ToString() + "'>" + t.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString() + "</span>" +
                    "</div>"+
                "</div>"));
```

This one doesn't allow the `CheckBox` to be checked when clicking the `Label`.  I inspected the code and the `Label` is showing up as a `span`

```
         caPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='row caSectionRow'>" +
                "<div class='col-md-6'>"));

                    Label aName = new Label();
                    aName.ID = "AButton" + t.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
                    aName.Attributes.Add("class", "caLabel");
                    aName.Attributes.Add("onmouseenter", "slideDescriptionDown(this.id);");
                    aName.Attributes.Add("onmouseleave", "slideDescriptionDown(this.id);");
                    aName.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + t.Rows[i]["NAME"].ToString();

                    CheckBox aCheckBox = new CheckBox();
                    aCheckBox.ID = "checkbox" + t.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();

                caPanel.Controls.Add(aCheckBox);
                caPanel.Controls.Add(aName);

                caPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
                    "<div class='alert alert-info aDescription' id='descArea" + t.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "'>" +
                        "<span id='desc" + t.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "'>" + t.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString() + "</span>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error lied within the JS function itself when trying to display the descArea for the **first option** I proposed.  I didn't have the `ID` for the descArea correct.  It was prepended with the `MainContent_aContent_` to fulfill `UniqueID` property all controls must have in ASP.NET.

[When is the ctl00 prefix added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678228/when-is-the-ctl00-prefix-added)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss(v=vs.100).ASPX